# PowerDNS not listening

Tags: debian-wheezy, dns-zone, powerdns

I just migrated from Bind9 to PowerDNS on my Debian 7 x86_64, and now DNS requests are not going through. I am not familiar with PowerDNS config files, but I did go into `pdns.local` and specified `local-port=53`.

A quick `netstat -tul` shows:

```
root@example:~# netstat -tul
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:submission            *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:11211 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:pop3                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:imap2                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:http-alt              *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:tproxy                *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssmtp                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:imaps                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:pop3s                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10024 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:10025 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                 *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:submission         [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap2              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssmtp              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3s              [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 localhost.localdo:11211 *:*
udp        0      0 example.com:ntp       *:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:ntp           *:*
udp        0      0 localhost.localdoma:ntp *:*
udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*
```

So PowerDNS isn't even listening. I looked through the iptables and found no reference to DNS or port 53, which leads me to believe that iptables is not blocking it. I have ISPConfig 3 installed, and the same exact zone worked on my Bind configuration. So why isn't PowerDNS listening on port 53?

Comment: Silly question, but can you verify that the PowerDNS service is up and running?

Comment: Yes, it is running. `service pdns status` says it is running.

Comment: This is not a good thing to hash our on serverfault i fear. For example I would ask you to provide your configuration in order to be of any help. Also what do the logfiles (depending on your OS/distri) say?

Answer (score 0):

I had to tell mine specifically what IP address to bind to using `local-address`

```
local-address=A.B.C.D
```